# Local Host Did Not Send Any Data

Tags: nginx, dockerfile, docker-container, docker-image, dockerhub

I created a docker image with this docker file

```
# Use latest nginx image as base image.
FROM nginx:latest
# Install wget and unzip
RUN apt-get update -y && \
  apt-get install wget -y && \
  apt-get install unzip -y

# Change Directory to the path that host nginx default website
WORKDIR /usr/share/nginx/html

# Download source code from github repository
RUN wget https://github.com/jcrichlee/second-semester-counter/archive/refs/heads/main.zip

# Unzip folder
RUN unzip main.zip

# Copy files into nginx html directory
RUN cp -r second-semester-counter-main/. .

# Delete unwanted files
RUN rm -rf second-semester-counter-main main.zip

# Expose container port
EXPOSE 80
```

I created a container with this image at port 9080:8080 but I am seeing localhost didn’t send any data on the browser

I was expecting to see the website on my browser but that didn't happen